# How do I find out if a given lat lon is in a KML Linear ring using shapely?

Tags: python, kml, shapely

I'm a GIS basic/novice user.

I have some LinearRings in a KML file that give the areas for a bunch of different regions.  And then I (will) have some lat lons that I want to test to see if they're in any of the (about 8) different regions that I have LinearRings for.  I want to use python and shapely looks like it's a good fit, but it doesn't deal with kml data at all.

Is there a standard way to do things like load KML that I can then import into shapely?

Comment: Although I realize this is an old post would you care to help me out? Working with Python3 the code needed to change a bit for it to work e.g. line 1 : from urllib.request import urlopen But after all changes the output seems to be strange: <filter object at 0x0000000003948D30> Let me state i've changed nothing further then to make the original code work. Thank you Maurice

Comment: If you have a new question about python please ask a new question.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [Keytree](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/keytree/) and [FastKML](https://github.com/cleder/fastkml) parse KML placemarks into GeoJSON-ish objects that are easy to use with Shapely. Here's an example of using Keytree:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from xml.etree import ElementTree

import keytree
from shapely.geometry import Point, shape

# Parse the KML doc
doc = urlopen("http://pleiades.stoa.org/places/638753/kml").read()
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(doc)
kmlns = tree.tag.split('}')[0][1:]

# Find all Polygon elements anywhere in the doc
elems = tree.findall(".//{%s}Polygon" % kmlns)

# Here's our point of interest
p = Point(28.722144580890763, 37.707799701548467)

# Filter polygon elements using this lambda (anonymous function)
# keytree.geometry() makes a GeoJSON-like geometry object from an
# element and shape() makes a Shapely object of that.
hits = filter(
    lambda e: shape(keytree.geometry(e)).contains(p),
    elems )

print hits
# Output:  [<Element {http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}Polygon at ...>]
```

Once you've found the elements that contain the point, you can use the xml module's etree API to inspect them further.

Comment: I was wrestling with this all afternoon today, but then I finally figured out that keytree.geometry() is pulling things in as lon,lat not lat,lon.  when I switched my code so that I was encoding points like so: p = Point(lon, lat)  then it finally worked for me. Thanks, so much, Sean!